# How can I use async GM_xmlhttpRequest to return values in original order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to make a Tampermonkey script to update dates on some site.
I got an array of id's from a site, and I'm requesting data from it with the id of the array. After that, I have to return data of each Input.

As the function is `async`, it returns data in a random order, but I need those new arrays to return in the original order. I have tried sync and `Promise`s, but the first is too slow and I haven't understood the second.

I can sort ids, but I also got the dates which are in the order of the first Array, so I don't know how to achieve the same order as the second id array.

Here's the code:

```
id = GM_getValue('id');

for (let i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Updating " + (i + 1) + " Title");

      GM_xmlhttpRequest({
          method: "GET",
          url: "***" + id[i] + "/***",
          onload: function(response) {
            $(response.responseText).find("#main-form :input").each(function(x) {
                if (x == 0) ids.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
                if (x == 1) array.push($(this).val()));
            });
        }
      });
  }, i * 333);
}
```

Comment: You can't guarantee the order those asynchronous requests get returned, even with the 333ms delay between each being sent. Using an array of promises and Promise.all() would fix that

Comment: @charlietfl Oh... Completly forgot that this is asynchronous... Stupid mistake...
Thanks for help!

Comment: @charlietfl So...
I read about Promises, but I have no idea how it works :/
Could You give me an example?

Comment: Even though the order of the response are not predictable, the callback that gets called is tied to the request. That is, The callback for `id[0]` will be called for the `id[0]` request even though this may happen after `id[1]`. The simple solution to get the responses with the original order is to set the arrays instead of using `.push()`: `ids[i] = ...` and `array[i] = ...`

Comment: @slebetman I actually tried it, but strange things was occurring

Comment: why are you reading this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Promises to execute the `GET` requests in a specific order. Here's an example:

```js
id = GM_getValue('id');

function makeGetRequest(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
      method: "GET",
      url: url,
      onload: function(response) {
        resolve(response.responseText);
      },
      onerror: function(error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
  console.log("Updating " + (i + 1) + " Title");
  try {
    const response = await makeGetRequest("***" + id[i] + "/***");
    $(response).find("#main-form :input").each(function(x) {
      if (x == 0) ids.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
      if (x == 1) array.push($(this).val());
    });
  } catch (error) { // in case the GET request fails
    console.error("Request failed with error code", error.status, ". Message is ", error.responseText);
  }
}
```

In this example, I've created a `makeGetRequest()` function with returns a promise, which is [resolved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) on GET success, but [rejected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) on failure.

`await` waits for the Promise to settle before moving on and the `try` exists to catch Promise rejection (if the GET fails).

References:

- [`Promise` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).
- [`await` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript：

```js
export enum HttpDataType {
  JSON = "JSON"
}

import {HttpDataType} from "./enum/HttpDataType";

export default class Http {

  static get(option: { url: string, dataType?: HttpDataType, synchronous?: boolean, onload?: Function }) {
    option['method'] = 'GET';

    if (option.synchronous) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // @ts-ignore
        GM_xmlhttpRequest({
          ...option,
          onload: (response) => {
            resolve(option.dataType === HttpDataType.JSON ? JSON.parse(response.responseText) : response.responseText);
          },
          onerror: (error) => {
            reject(error);
          }
        });
      })
    } else {
      const onload1 = function (details) {
        let response;
        if (option.dataType === HttpDataType.JSON) {
          response = JSON.parse(details.responseText);
        } else {
          response = details.response;
        }
        option.onload(response);
      }
      // @ts-ignore
      GM_xmlhttpRequest({...option, onload: onload1});
    }
  }
}
```

```js
static async getXxx() {
  let response = await Http.get({
    url: '……',
    dataType: HttpDataType.JSON,
    synchronous: true
  });

  // @ts-ignore
  if (!response || response.status !== 'success') {
    console.error('getXxx error', response);
  }

  // @ts-ignore
  return response.data;
}

this.getXxx().then((data: any) => {
  // ……
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).